# Determine if an instance of a service is running and kill it

Tags: java, android

I have an Android Service, let's say "Service.java"

I start an instance and pass a unique id to each instance of the service that I start (so that I don't have two service with the same uid running at the same time):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Service.class);
intent.putExtra("KEY", uid);
startService(intent);
```

Say I set a variable in "Service.java" to this uid:

```
private String uid;
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, final int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    if(intent != null) {
        Bundle infoBundle = intent.getExtras();
        this.uid = infoBundle.getString("KEY");
    }

    ...
}

public String getUid() { return this.uid; }
```

Is there a way to somehow check if an instance of "Service.java" is running with a given uid and kill it?

I have a list of key/value pairs that I want to start instances of this service at specific times of the day, but if the user "disables" a certain time slot (key/value pair), I want the service to stop.

Backstory:

I have an application that starts a service 30 minutes before a given time to poll a data source for changes. The service kills itself after the data feed is no longer available.

If the user "unfavorites/disables" this time slot (key/value pair - uid), I don't want the service running for the next 30 minutes, so I would like to kill it as soon as it's "unfavorited/disabled"

I may be going about this the wrong way.

Either way, input is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look at this more as: your service needs to know when the data model changes. In this case, the data model is the "list of key/value pairs", each with an enabled/disabled status.

Assuming that this is being stored in a database, `SharedPreferences`, or a file, with a singleton cache for rapid access, then here are three choices for letting the service know about the data model change:

1. Use an event bus or some other listener pattern, so if the service is around, it finds out about the change and can take some appropriate steps. If your service is running in a separate process, the event bus would have to be system-level broadcasts (in contrast to `LocalBroadcastManager`, which is an in-process event bus).
2. Front the data model with a `ContentProvider` and use a `ContentObserver` to be notified about changes (which is like swatting a fly with a Buick, but, hey, it's an option).
3. Call `startService()` when you change the data model, with some information (e.g., custom action string) to let the service know that this is a "check your data model" event. The downside of this approach is that you then start the service if it was not already started, though presumably the service would realize if there is nothing to do and just stop itself right away.

Personally, I'd go with option #1.

---

But, to get back to your literal question, the only good way to pull data out of a service on demand is to use the binding pattern, where your client connects to the service via `bindService()` and the service publishes an API in the form of a `Binder`. This is not mutually exclusive with your current approach. However, the downside of this approach is akin to #3 above: if the service is not already running, the act of trying to bind to it will create an instance of the service.

There's nothing stopping you from taking the "oh, the service is a singleton, so I'll track its state via some `static` field somewhere" approach. I've even done that on occasion for scrap apps, though it makes me queasy. It also only works for services in the same process as the rest of your app; if your service is in a separate process, this approach doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your response @CommonsWare

I think my main problem was that I was getting wrapped around the idea that I needed to immediately kill the service on an "onClick" event.

If I make the onClick update the SharedPreferences and the Service - which is performing a task every minute - checks the SharedPreferences for whether or not this Service is considered a "favorite" I can cause the Service to either continue doing its work (if it is still enabled) or kill itself (if it has been disabled).

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation,

> Request that a given application service be started. The Intent can
>   either contain the complete class name of a specific service
>   implementation to start, or an abstract definition through the action
>   and other fields of the kind of service to start. If this service is
>   not already running, it will be instantiated and started (creating a
>   process for it if needed); if it is running then it remains running.

But if you are using startService();

you should specify when to stop the service within the service,

And also you should know that the service will be running on the main thread (Which block the main thread), unless you initiate a new thread in the service, or use an IntentService which handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself when it runs out of work.

You can have a thread pool implementation. and have a queue of jobs and before you put anything to a queue, you can check it it already there.

You can have these jobs as runnable and have your UUid for each job. You can remove them interrupt them do what ever you like with it.

Here is a [cool example](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/create-threadpool.html), Complex but work fine :)